# React Native ToolbarAndroid - How to set RTL?

Tags: react-native, android-toolbar

I am using a ToolbarAndroid, and I need it in a RTL configuration. So I followed the official docs:

- Set rtl={true} on the ToolbarAndroid Component
- Added android:supportsRtl="true" to the AndroidManifest.xml
- Added
  getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
  to the onCreate() method in the main activity

But the app crashes in Genymotion emulator when it loads:
[image]

How can I debug the error? (I assume it's an exception that is thrown inside the onCreate)

**Update:**
I was facing the error because I forgot to call super.onCreate(). Now it doesn't crash but the tool bar is not aligned to RTL. Nothing happened. Any advices?

Comment: What does Android Monitor logs look like when the crash happens ?

Comment: Can you try asking Sameer? I believe he implemented the RTL support: https://github.com/lxsameer